# nfs error on rhel6

Tags: linux, ldap, nfs

I have a server with NFS, LDAP, and Autofs configured for export the `/home`, but every time i try mount nfs in my client desktop, the receive this error in Server: `Cannot export /home, possibly unsupported filesystem or fsid= required`. I am using the command `mount -t nfs server:/home` for testing the export of `/home` directory.

My config files
Server

```
#/etc/auto.master
/home auto.home
#auto.home
* -fstype=nfs,rw server:/home/&
# /etc/exports
/home *(rw,fsid=0)
```

Someone can please  help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The automounter will take control of the mount points specifyied in any of the automounter maps, in this case /home.  You will be unable to manually mount anything under /home unless you disable the automounter (autofs) process.

However, I'd suggest that you perform your test using /mnt over using /home.  This will not interfere with the automounter.